# in Python 2.7.5, why is "if (code)" valid syntax but "elif (same code)" isn't?

Tags: python, syntax

here is the entire module. All the "elif" statements are valid syntax if changed into "if" statements

```
def processRGB(item, matrix):
    threshhold = 229
    red, green, blue = matrix[0, 0]
    if red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 0)
    red, green, blue = matrix[item[0].size[0] - 1, 0]
    elif red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 90)
    red, green, blue = matrix[0, item[0].size[1] - 1]
    elif red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 180)
    red, green, blue = matrix[item[0].size[0] - 1, item[0].size[1] - 1]
    elif red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 270)
    final = picture[0].crop(boundary)
    final.load()
    return final
```

Comment: Because you cannot have standalone `elif` blocks. They always have to belong to an `if` block. **Have a close look at the indentation.**

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. Indent those `red,green,blue =` things if that is what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the `if` statement ends as soon as your indentation changes. And you cannot have an `elif` without an immediately preceding `if`. I'm guessing you want your code to look like this, which is valid syntax because of the difference in indentation.

```
def processRGB(item, matrix):
    threshhold = 229
    red, green, blue = matrix[0, 0]
    if red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 0)
        red, green, blue = matrix[item[0].size[0] - 1, 0]
    elif red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 90)
        red, green, blue = matrix[0, item[0].size[1] - 1]
    elif red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 180)
        red, green, blue = matrix[item[0].size[0] - 1, item[0].size[1] - 1]
    elif red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
        picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 270)
    final = picture[0].crop(boundary)
    final.load()
    return final
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements immediately before the `elif` lines should be indented to the same level as the line before them if they are meant to activate if the previous `if` statement is true. Otherwise, the `elif` should be an `if` because you're onto another code block.

Answer (score 0):

It is because :

```
if red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
    picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 0)
```

Above if ends here because if scope is defined by indentation.

```
red, green, blue = matrix[item[0].size[0] - 1, 0]
```

Because there is some code in between "if" and "elif" statement. "elif" is not related to above "if" and we cannot specify "elif" as a standalone statement. It should be linked with "if" or other "elif" statment, which is not in this case.

```
elif red <= threshhold and green <= threshhold and blue <= threshhold:
    picture, boundary = RGBUpright(item, matrix, 90)
```

Same explanation goes with other "elif".

Please let me know if it is not clear.